# I am not able to change my Get JSON Data and create dynamically form in angular 8

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, angular8

My Post JSON is Like

```
  {
 "items":[
    {
  "templatename":"Defult",
  "tasks":[
    "task-1",
    "task-2 ",
    "task-3",
    "task-4",
    "task-5",
    "task-6",
    "task-7"
  ]
},
{
  "templatename":"Eccormce",
  "tasks":[
    "task-1 ",
    "task-2",
    "task-3",
    "task-4",
    "task-5"
  ]
},
{
  "templatename":"co-oprate",
  "tasks":[
    "task-1",
    "task-2",
    "task-3"
  ]
}
```

]
}

But I get in my API JSON like that

```
  {
"data":{
"id": 10,
"Default":[
"Task 1 ",
"Task 2",
"Task 3"
],
"E-commerce":[
"Task 1",
"Task 2",
"Task 3"
],
"Corporate":[
"Task 1"
    ]
},
```

"message": "success",
"status": 200
}

Please suggest and guide me. How can I change and create `formArray` inside `formArray` dynamically in get this API JSON and convert my get JSON in to a my Post JSON. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

according to the `JSON` you post your `form` should look like that

```
... 

all your imports

export interface Items {
    templatename: string,
    tasks: string[]
}

...

form: FormGroup;
items: Items[];

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

ngOnInit() {

    this.form = this.fb.group({
        items: this.fb.array([])
    });

}

get items(): formArray {
    return this.form.get('items') as formArray
}
```

now push your objects as `formGroup` to the items array

```
this.items.push(this.form.group({
    templatename: "Defult",
    tasks: [
         "task-1",
         "task-2",
         "task-3"
    ];
}))
```